# How do I copy a character's appearance to a new save?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

I decided to restart my play-through of Baldur's Gate 3 and want to copy my old character's appearance over to my new save. Is there a way for me to copy over my old character's appearance or review what options I chose for them during character creation?

Comment: Within the same save, you can do a complete respec including class if you speak to Withers. I don't know if it is possible to copy your appearance to another save.

Comment: I would imagine for now you'd need a mod for this.